# Carrierwave: Split multipage PDF into several images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, carrierwave

I'm trying to split multipage PDFs for my Rails application and then convert the pages to png. In the best case I would end up with one entry per page in my image Model.

This is what I've got so far:

```
def generate_png
  manipulate! do |image, index|
    image.format = 'png'
    image.write("#{Rails.root}/public/#{store_dir}/image-#{index}.png")
  end
end
```

Unfortunately it only gives me image-0.png for the first frame and nothing for the other frames. Where am I going wrong?

How would I generate a new entry in my image model for each frame? Something like

```
model.images.new :image => image
```

?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you split pdf file into images if the the file name is file.pdf the results will be multi images with the same name, with attached number like file-0.png ,file-1.png .......
so you need to load all converted images from pdf and and convert them in any format you want

it gives you image-0.png because the return of spliting pdf file is only the first image which is the first page in the pdf file

you can upload the file normally and do after_create methods

```
def generate_image_form_pdf 
  file = @magazine.file
  file_name=file.path.sub(".pdf",".jpg")
  system("convert #{file.path}  #{file_name}")
end
```

the above method will create jpg images from the pdf file and store them in the same directory and the same name of the original pdf file

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does not work for me so far, but I discovered that the command convert #{file.path}  #{file_name} returns only the first page on my machine. Seems to be a problem with my machine in general.

Comment: When i have all those images, how do I insert them into my model? Just looping through them in my filesystem? Seems a bit inelegant to me...

Comment: you can store links as array of links and serilaize it as an array in your db. ................

how to serialize array? =>

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html